# Multiple definition error on the same line

Tags: c++, qt

GCC appears to be complaining about multiple definitions of a function.  I get two errors which both point to the same line:

```
arControls.cpp:5: error: multiple definition of `arControls::arControls(QCheckBox*, QSpinBox*, QSpinBox*)'
```

arcontrols.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
class QCheckBox;
class QSpinBox;

class arControls: public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public: 
   arControls(void) = delete;
   arControls(QCheckBox* arCB,
              QSpinBox* sb1,
              QSpinBox* sb2);

protected:
   QCheckBox* _arCB;
   QSpinBox* _sb1;
   QSpinBox* _sb2;

};
```

arcontrols.cpp:

```
#include "arControls.h"

arControls::arControls(QCheckBox* arCB,
                       QSpinBox* sb1,
                       QSpinBox* sb2)
{
  //Populate pointers
  _arCB = arCB;
  _sb1 = sb1;
  _sb2 = sb2;
}
```

This situation appears to be different from [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233947/multiple-definition-error-on-the-same-line-c).  I have not put implementation into a header or included implementation elsewhere in the code.

The header is only included twice.  Once in the implementation.

QT Designer using gcc complier.

Comment: I don't know whether this relates to your error, but why do you have `#pragma once` in the implementation file rather than the header file (which would be more typical, I think)?

Comment: This `#pragma once` seems like you don't fully understand what it does. Are you including that cpp somewhere?

Comment: Do you have include guards in the header file?  Make sure no one includes the cpp file anywhere.

Comment: I put the the #pragma once in there to see if anything would change.  It didn't.

Comment: I checked for inclusion of the .cpp before asking, I've since moved the #pragma once back to the header with no change in behavior.  Editing the question to reflect the current state.

Comment: How are you compiling `arcontrols.cpp`?  In particular, are you compiling that code more than once, or linking its object file more than once?  You'll need to show the full command that's emitting the error.

Comment: There is not enough here for us to be able to help.  Can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: @TobySpeight,  arcontrols.cpp is in the project once.  I'll see if I can isolate the command generating the error.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I often shrink from stripping down my entire project to find the cause of problems like this.  I'll try to turn a new leaf and be a good sport about it, knowing I might find the answer along the way.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I created a test project with a main function that creates an instance of arControls.  It built with no probelm, which leads me to believe there is a structural problem with my full application, althogh I am quite certain there is no inclusion of the .cpp, so there may indeed not be enough to go on. I will find the answer, and I am hopeful it will get an upvote. Perhaps someone can suggest a helpful strategy.

Comment: Really the only strategy there is, is to make a [mcve].  We can't help you fix your problem if the problem isn't in the question.  Is `arcontrols.cpp` really just the constructor?  If it is not, and there are other functions in there, do any of them give you a multiple definition error?  If it is, the only way I can think you got this error is the cpp file is included in another cpp file somewhere, or your compiling the and linking to the cpp twice.

Comment: When you get a compiler error for a multiple definition, doesn't the next line of output tell you where the other definition is?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I appreciate the article under your link.  Before posting my question, I cut down the arControls class, which was already pretty small, it is new, removing a few inline "set" and "get" functions from the header.  The code in the question generated the error.  Now having attempted a "bottom up" reproduction of the error, I'm now faced with the more laborious "top down" approach attempting to isolate the problem by cutting parts off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the commentors mentioned it appears this kind of problem is most often caused by trying to compile the same file twice.

- Including an implementation (.cpp) file is a quick way to do this.
- Another way to compile a file twice is to include it twice in the project, which is what created this question.  It happened in a sneaky way which did not manifest in the IDE, in this case, QT Creator.

In this case, arControls.h and arControls.cpp, shown in the question, were created, then explicitly added to the project by using the graphical IDE by right clicking on the folder then selecting "Add existing file".  The file showed up in the tree as expected.  Adding the file this way had the effect of editing the project file.  The IDE found an instance of SOURCES and tacked on the explicitly added file:

```
SOURCES     += $$COMMON/status/explicitfile1.cpp \
               $$COMMON/status/explicitfile2.cpp \
               $$COMMON/status/explicitfile3.cpp \
        ../src/arControls.cpp
```

Looking elsewhere in the project files, we find these lines:

```
SRC     = $$ROOT/src
INCLUDEPATH +=  $$SRC 
HEADERS     +=  $$SRC/*.h
SOURCES     +=  $$SRC/*.cpp
```

Earlier developers had used wildcards in the project file to include all files in the src folder.  The added files had not shown up in the IDE when they were added manually, and the IDE never came forth with a hint that the file had been added to the project twice.  **Only one copy was visible in the source tree**.